# How to get order recipient on WooCommerce mail template

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I need to get `woocommerce_new_order_recipient` in my `email-order-details.php` template mail because I need to hide the product price row if the recipient is not `test@test.com`.

How can I do that?
Thanks all.

Comment: the filter hook `woocommerce_new_order_recipient` is made to add or replace recipients from New order email notification sent to the admin... So it has nothing to do with hiding product prices in an email template.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec alright. I have to `recipients` but I have to hide the price of the product inside the email from one of them.

Comment: In the template `email-order-details.php` you can use the defined variable `$email` and to get the recipient, you will use: `$recipient = $email->recipient;`… But the problem is that the **product price** is located on the template file `emails/email-order-items.php` and **where the `$email` variable is not defined**.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec perfect, thanks for the hint. I will try to figure out.